# What is the datastore used by Google for Google Instant?

Tags: database, google

My understanding is that Google is not using MapReduce for Google Instant, but I can't find anywhere that states what they're using as the datastore for Google Instant. What is the datastore used by Google for Google Instant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably the closest you will get to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670831/how-does-google-instant-work). Without talking to someone who actually worked on the project. Or more information is released to the public.

The link above contains this answer. It would have been hard to get point across without images. I would appreciate if you give the original poster up votes as well if you found this answer useful.

**UPDATE**: Google have just published a blog article called Google Instant, behind the scenes. It's an interesting read, and obviously related to this question. You can read how they tackled the extra load (5-7X according to the article) on the server-side, for example. The answer below examines what happens on the client-side:

Examining with Firebug, Google is doing an Ajax GET request on every keypress:

[image]

I guess it's working the same way as the auto completion. However this time, it also returns the search results of the partially complete search phrase in JSON format.

Examining one of the JSON responses while typing "Stack Overflow":

[image]

We can see that the JSON response contains the content to construct the search results as we type.

The formatted JSON responses look something like this:

```
{
    e: "j9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO",
    c: 1,
    u: "http://www.google.com/search?hl\x3den\x26expIds\x3d17259,24472,24923,25260,25901,25907,26095,26446,26530\x26sugexp\x3dldymls\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dStack%20Overflow\x26cp\x3d6\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy\x26aq\x3df\x26aqi\x3dg4g-o1\x26aql\x3d\x26oq\x3dStack+\x26gs_rfai\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26fp\x3df97fdf10596ae095\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d1\x26psi\x3dj9iHTO3xBo2CONvDzaEO12839712156911",
    d: "\x3clink rel\x3dprefetch href\x3d\x22https://stackoverflow.com/\x22\x3e\x3cscript\x3eje.pa(_loc, \x27rso\x27, \x27\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3clink rel\\x3dprefetch href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/\\x22\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNERidL9Hb6OvGW93_Y6MRj3aTdMVA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CBYQFjAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3eA language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3e\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.com/\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:U1GC2GYOToIJ:stackoverflow.com/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d1\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFfKMag7Tq8CMbbfu8Gcj_GjukTbA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CBgQIDAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:stackoverflow.com/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CBkQHzAA\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3ctable class\\x3dslk style\\x3d\\x22border-collapse:collapse;margin-top:4px\\x22\\x3e\\x3ctr\\x3e\\x3ctd style\\x3d\\x22padding-left:14px;vertical-align:top\\x22\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/questions\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHmP78gEctJKvBrydP2c52F_FEjvA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CBoQqwMoADAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eQuestions\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNGZF-qwWVTZOWPlr4vgSA7qB64LLQ\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CBsQqwMoATAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eAsk Question\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/users/135152/omg-ponies\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNE9zo6Qi_AM1bjmPGeMGfbnPi3niA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CBwQqwMoAjAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eOMG Ponies\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22http://careers.stackoverflow.com/\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNEaqlBrfDcc1gdPZ6dgthff0s5WmA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CB0QqwMoAzAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCareers\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3ctd style\\x3d\\x22padding-left:14px;vertical-align:top\\x22\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/about\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNEqgPttrXj3r4o3TZHX5WaWvFe1HQ\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CB4QqwMoBDAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eAbout\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/faq\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNF3X3eRc0RsxYynXZhhbyYkuKWZ5g\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CB8QqwMoBTAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eThe FAQ\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22http://blog.stackoverflow.com/\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNG7KphjK6RuC5cj-6U5jeuvipt5dg\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CCAQqwMoBjAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eBlog\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dsld\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dsla href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/users\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x271\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFfN_wcGm4HE5XpDxvcH4bIrkv2dw\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CCEQqwMoBzAA\\x27)\\x22\\x3eUsers\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3ctr\\x3e\\x3ctd colspan\\x3d2 style\\x3d\\x22padding-left:14px;vertical-align:top\\x22\\x3e\\x3cdiv style\\x3d\\x22padding-top:6px\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca class\\x3dfl href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3d+site:stackoverflow.com+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CCIQrAM\\x22\\x3eMore results from stackoverflow.com\\x26nbsp;\\x26raquo;\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c/table\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22https://stackoverflow.com/questions\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x272\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHmP78gEctJKvBrydP2c52F_FEjvA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CCUQFjAB\\x27)\\x22\\x3eHottest Questions - \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3eHello \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e! I\\x26#39;m working with someone else\\x26#39;s PHP function that works fine as long as I pass it at least three arguments. If I pass it two argument, \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3e\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.com/questions\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:6S_0sErDKfQJ:stackoverflow.com/questions+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d2\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x272\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNH7WHzefYlnS05ln4j6rzfE3byDKg\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CCcQIDAB\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:stackoverflow.com/questions+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CCgQHzAB\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x273\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNEAxaeWmWtD7cBcmZ5QBMsTRNbnCw\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CCkQFjAC\\x27)\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStack overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3eIn software, a \\x3cem\\x3estack overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e occurs when too much memory is used on the call stack. The call stack contains a limited amount of memory,  often determined at \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3een.wikipedia.org/wiki/\\x3cb\\x3eStack\\x3c/b\\x3e_\\x3cb\\x3eoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:mWu8b0BQAmwJ:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d3\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x273\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFG_5ndK-KmWJy6s3pOsi8lsxqEZg\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CCsQIDAC\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CCwQHzAC\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://blog.stackoverflow.com/\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x274\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNG7KphjK6RuC5cj-6U5jeuvipt5dg\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CC0QFjAD\\x27)\\x22\\x3eBlog – \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3e6 Sep 2010 \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e The latest version of the \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e Trilogy Creative Commons Data Dump is now available. This reflects all public  data in … \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3eblog.\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.com/\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:iqtvg9Ge1c0J:blog.stackoverflow.com/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d4\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x274\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFX2P2-RTCs_GaR6NgSw30p007UEA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CC8QIDAD\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:blog.stackoverflow.com/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CDAQHzAD\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\x27,_ss);\x3c/script\x3e"
}/*""*/{
    e: "j9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO",
    c: 1,
    u: "http://www.google.com/search?hl\x3den\x26expIds\x3d17259,24472,24923,25260,25901,25907,26095,26446,26530\x26sugexp\x3dldymls\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dStack%20Overflow\x26cp\x3d6\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy\x26aq\x3df\x26aqi\x3dg4g-o1\x26aql\x3d\x26oq\x3dStack+\x26gs_rfai\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26fp\x3df97fdf10596ae095\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d1\x26psi\x3dj9iHTO3xBo2CONvDzaEO12839712156911",
    d: "\x3cscript\x3eje.pa(_loc, \x27rso\x27, \x27\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg style\\x3d\\x22margin-left:16px\\x22\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r hcw\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x275\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNGnAJSxUa4GLcg-E7PNvIFmPC53gQ\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CDEQFjAE\\x27)\\x22\\x3epodcasts - Blog – \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s hc\\x22\\x3eJoel and Jeff sit down with our new community coordinator, Robert Cartaino, to record a “bonus” podcast discussing the future of \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e and Stack \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3eblog.\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.com/category/podcasts/\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:JT0sWmmtiAEJ:blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d5\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x275\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNErCiLBch55HA8i5BAdChcmQYH8nw\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CDMQIDAE\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CDQQHzAE\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x276\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHG9l1PMbilYkhohNFuj3g6ce1LuA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CDUQFjAF\\x27)\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStackOverflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3eJoel and Jeff sit down with our new community coordinator, Robert Cartaino, to discuss the future of \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e and Stack Exchange 2.0. \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3eitc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.html\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:8MkFpx7D4wYJ:itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d6\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x276\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFP62Bg_o2kaz3jzXxzsrTs_7RdNA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CDcQIDAF\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CDgQHzAF\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://support.microsoft.com/kb/145799\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x277\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHzyj5rHEX7IiyFWnP0ziE3B32rGg\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CDkQFjAG\\x27)\\x22\\x3eHow to Troubleshoot Windows Internal \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e Error Messages\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3eThis article lists steps to help you troubleshoot problems with \\x3cem\\x3estack overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e errors in  Windows. Stacks are reserved memory that programs use to process \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3esupport.microsoft.com/kb/145799\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:ECO9ORCsraAJ:support.microsoft.com/kb/145799+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d7\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x277\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHYsox9EW1Ye9Nn2G6WQzEpJDOzcw\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CDsQIDAG\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:support.microsoft.com/kb/145799+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CDwQHzAG\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x278\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHcEPoch5soLj2CpLpRfnW-Z2-aLw\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CD0QFjAH\\x27)\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStackOverflow\\x3c/em\\x3e DevDays » Home\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStackOverflow\\x3c/em\\x3e Dev Days is run by Carsonified, so please give us a shout if you need anything or are interested in sponsoring the event. \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3e\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.carsonified.com/\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:uhl8NPgikN0J:stackoverflow.carsonified.com/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d8\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x278\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFf9Vl5L3FaQGPapUpIFw5gqVUCnA\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CD8QIDAH\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:stackoverflow.carsonified.com/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CEAQHzAH\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://stackoverflow.org/\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x279\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNF-YrPvTLTJlFFDJrJE0cjGdlOpbg\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CEEQFjAI\\x27)\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStackOverflow\\x3c/em\\x3e.org\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStackOverflow\\x3c/em\\x3e.org began as the merging of two ideas that have been kicking around in my head for years. First, I wanted a dorky programming-related domain \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3e\\x3cb\\x3estackoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e.org/\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:u0dIlJW-XMYJ:stackoverflow.org/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d9\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x279\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNHcJcV2QVybr6voztyPwHCrNOOD1w\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CEMQIDAI\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e - \\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3drelated:stackoverflow.org/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;tbo\\x3d1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CEQQHzAI\\x22\\x3eSimilar\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\\x3c!--m--\\x3e\\x3cli class\\x3dg\\x3e\\x3ch3 class\\x3d\\x22r\\x22\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/\\x22 class\\x3dl onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x2710\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFYQ5E8irNUCpRsbOHHyfc0oqGpWw\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CEUQFjAJ\\x27)\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/h3\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22s\\x22\\x3e\\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e. Nigel Jones. Nigel Jones has over 20 years of experience designing electronic circuits and firmware. (full bio). Pages. Contact Nigel. Links \\x3cb\\x3e...\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3cbr\\x3e\\x3cspan class\\x3df\\x3e\\x3ccite\\x3eembeddedgurus.com/\\x3cb\\x3estack\\x3c/b\\x3e-\\x3cb\\x3eoverflow\\x3c/b\\x3e/\\x3c/cite\\x3e - \\x3cspan class\\x3dgl\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q\\x3dcache:Rl_rUfEG_fIJ:embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/+Stack+Overflow\\x26amp;cd\\x3d10\\x26amp;hl\\x3den\\x26amp;ct\\x3dclnk\\x22 onmousedown\\x3d\\x22return rwt(this,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x2710\\x27,\\x27AFQjCNFqMjsc1pBI9JexjMSPY7wm5QLI8w\\x27,\\x27\\x27,\\x270CEcQIDAJ\\x27)\\x22\\x3eCached\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/span\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c!--n--\\x3e\x27,_ss);\x3c/script\x3e"
}/*""*/{
    e: "j9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO",
    c: 1,
    u: "http://www.google.com/search?hl\x3den\x26expIds\x3d17259,24472,24923,25260,25901,25907,26095,26446,26530\x26sugexp\x3dldymls\x26xhr\x3dt\x26q\x3dStack%20Overflow\x26cp\x3d6\x26pf\x3dp\x26sclient\x3dpsy\x26aq\x3df\x26aqi\x3dg4g-o1\x26aql\x3d\x26oq\x3dStack+\x26gs_rfai\x3d\x26pbx\x3d1\x26fp\x3df97fdf10596ae095\x26tch\x3d1\x26ech\x3d1\x26psi\x3dj9iHTO3xBo2CONvDzaEO12839712156911",
    d: "\x3cscript\x3eje.p(_loc,\x27botstuff\x27,\x27 \\x3cdiv id\\x3dbrs style\\x3d\\x22clear:both;margin-bottom:17px;overflow:hidden\\x22\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3d\\x22med\\x22 style\\x3d\\x22text-align:left\\x22\\x3eSearches related to \\x3cem\\x3eStack Overflow\\x3c/em\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dbrs_col\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+error\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CEkQ1QIoAA\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3eerror\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+internet+explorer\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CEoQ1QIoAQ\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3einternet explorer\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dfix+stack+overflow\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CEsQ1QIoAg\\x22\\x3e\\x3cb\\x3efix\\x3c/b\\x3e stack overflow\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+xp\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CEwQ1QIoAw\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3exp\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3cdiv class\\x3dbrs_col\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+javascript\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CE0Q1QIoBA\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3ejavascript\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+java\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CE4Q1QIoBQ\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3ejava\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+c%2B%2B\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CE8Q1QIoBg\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3ec++\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3cp\\x3e\\x3ca href\\x3d\\x22/search?hl\\x3den\\x26amp;q\\x3dstack+overflow+windows+xp\\x26amp;revid\\x3d-1\\x26amp;sa\\x3dX\\x26amp;ei\\x3dj9iHTLXlLNmXOJLQ3cMO\\x26amp;sqi\\x3d2\\x26amp;ved\\x3d0CFAQ1QIoBw\\x22\\x3estack overflow \\x3cb\\x3ewindows xp\\x3c/b\\x3e\\x3c/a\\x3e\\x3c/p\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e\\x3c/div\\x3e \x27,_ss);/*  */\x3c/script\x3e"
}/*""*/
```

Comment: please inline a summary of the link for offline usage.

Comment: If that link breaks (they do on SO from time to time) this answer loses all context.

Comment: @Thorbjørn @Tim I agree, there you guys sirs.

Answer (score 1):

MapReduce is an execution environment, BigTable and GoogleFS is used for storage. My understanding is that the changes required for Instant were more *evolutionary* than *revolutionry*. That is, the same basic processing is happening, but some tweaks were made to handle the increased volume.

If you think about it, there might be 5-7x more queries, but each time you type more characters in the search box you're really just *refining* your search, rather than doing a whole new one. So I imagine there may be some things you could do based on that knowledge so that you don't have to start the whole query from scratch each time.

Of course, I don't know for sure, and I doubt Google is going to release more information than what's already public...

Comment: Additionally, MapReduce isn't that fast - it's designed to give results in minutes or hours, not seconds.

Comment: MapReduce is an offline, batch-processing algorithm. It will crunch an entire dataset in minutes or hours. It is very fast because it can be distributed horizontally as far as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing very mysterious about it. The earlier version of google indexing, had to wait for the whole web to be crawled before it could process stuff. This is because the nature of MapReduce (the computation framework) is batch-oriented (It can only do stuff in large batches efficiently). The new version is based on BigTable somehow, though what specific variations they did to BigTable to make this possible are not known.

[Source](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/9/11/googles-colossus-makes-search-real-time-by-dumping-mapreduce.html)

Answer (score 0):

Map-reduce is never used for actual search, it's can be used however for generating  an index. Including index such as for Google Instant. For predictive text such index could be an [**trie** (prefix tree)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).